# Подключение внешних элементов

Tags: javascript, html, html5

суть в чем, на пхп можно подключить часть верстки которая находится в отдельном html файле скриптом,

```
include("HTML_файл_с_нужной_версткой")
```

Вроде так, но не суть, можно ли как то подобным образом подключать только джаваскриптом?))) или мб как то в html есть реализация через например ссылку на другой html файл??

Comment: Почему это не делать за счёт того же php?

Comment: Я делаю многостраничный сайт под песочницу типа гитхаба, там нельзя php, а навбар и футер для каждой страницы дублировать не хотелось) правки сложнее вносить

Comment: попробуйте импортировать html файл через тега <link>

Comment: @SomeUser, а ясно тогда)